# Why can't I create a Java Class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to create a new Java Class in one of my folders in Android Studio. When I right click, and click the option 'new', it offers me the option of creating a new C++ class, but does not offer any option to creating a Java Class.

[image: screenshot]

How do I create a new Java Class?

Comment: Given all those "Project not ready" messages, I would assume that there is some issue with your project overall. How did you create this project?

Comment: @CommonsWare is right. Has your project been fully built? I doubt. That's what is causing this problem.

Comment: The issue is not with your project. You  tried to create the class at the time of project indexing. Try it after indexing get completed

Comment: You can't access and make those component while the gradle is building the project or indexing.

Comment: "in one of my folders" We can't see where you're right clicking there.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments suggest, you might have a build issue, but you can just create an activity and not extend the activity class in order to have a normal java class

Answer (score 0):

I discovered at least one reason why android studio may not offer you the option to create a new Java Class.  If you have an unresolved gradle build sync issue the option to create a new Java Class may not be offered up as an option by Android Studio. That happened to me using Android Studio 2021.1.1.  The problem went away once I fixed the issue with my gradle.build script.  In my case, I had a dependency that I hadn't resolved properly.  It's a bit odd to see that happen especially since the project was created as a Java Project.  At any rate, there appears to be some dependency on having your gradle build not have any issues before Android Studio can determine that the project is a Java Project. I'm not sure if this problem happens in every circumstance because it was a new empty java library module that I observed that problem and I was trying to add my first class to that module.